# javascript reader to read html files in web browser - open source?

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript reader to read HTML5 documents ?

I am searching for a javascript reader which can be embedded in the browser and used to read the HTML5 files as book format. some solution which will let me view the files and go page by page and so on..
I could not find a html5 reader which is open source. 
Please let me know if there is any I could use. Thank you.

something like this: http://page-flip.com/

Comment: What?  What about an ordinary web browser?

Comment: Firefox/Chrome/Opera are opensource

Comment: @Pointy , I need to use the API inside an html file so that I can view the pages of the html document as a ebook reader. however, instead of pdf being supplied, I am supplying the html5 content to the reader. that is why i need a html5 reader which i can place in a script

Comment: Still not clear.  A web browser already knows how to show HTML5 documents.  You have not described your application clearly at all.

Comment: @Pointy,  I have a web page I am using in my application. I need to use the API which lets me view pages ( the pages are html5 documents) which are fed to the reader . The pages are viewed as a small frame inside the web browser, so that I can read all the html5 documents as books. So basically I need to find an open source solution to it which takes html5 as input

Comment: @Pointy.,  Trying to find something like this: http://pageflip.hu/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a useful tool I've come across, whilst researching a similar need:

- [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/)